# Is internal resistance relevant in motional EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage

When a conductor passes a magnetic field and connected to a circuit, the induced voltage is calculated via the motional EMF($\epsilon$): $$\epsilon=-vBL$$ Is the conductor's resistance (or internal resistance) relevant to the voltage? Meaning does it affect the magnitude of the voltage induced, or only determines the amount of current induced?

Trying to link ohm's law,voltage drop, and internal resistance to the motional emf. To put the question in another way, can two conductors of the same ($L$) moving at the same ($v$) in the same ($B$) strength of different resistance/internal resistance induce the same voltage however higher/lower current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful because that formula is only valid for a very limited set of field geometries. It is always better to derive EMF from the change of magnetic flux. To answer your question, the induced voltage at zero current does not depend on the resistance of the conductor. As soon as a load is connected to it, the effective voltage measured on the conductor will be reduced by $V=IR$, though.

Comment: Is $R$ the resistance of the whole conductor? Or only the piece relative to the magnetic field?